# In Biblatex APA style, how can I make the entire in text citation clickable instead of only the year?

Tags: biblatex

Right now, I can only redirect to my references if I click on the year. I would like this to work for the entire in text citation.

Comment: @AlanMunn-  Certainly that question is relevant and has an attractive answer, but did you read the last comment under the answer, saying it's out of date?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I updated the linked answer for a current version of `biblatex-apa`.